# can parent node support other shape?

Tags: javascript, cytoscape.js

I need to define the parent node shape custom, but if I assign the shape as usual, the shape remains rectangular (instead of a star shape like in the example):

```
{
  selector: 'node:parent',
  style: {
    'background-color': 'lightgrey',
    'shape': 'star',
    'border-color': 'cyan',
    'border-radius': '50',
    'background-fill': 'radial-gradient',
  }
}
```

---

Desired round parent shape:
[image: keylines]

Answer (score 3):

As described in [this](https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js/issues/1891) GitHub Issue, cytoscape.js does **not** support all node shapes for parent elements due to problems with the calculation of the parents `BoundingBox`.

The only supported shapes are:

- rectangle
- cutrectangle
- roundrectangle

Here is an example for this feature:

```js
var cy = (window.cy = cytoscape({
  container: document.getElementById("cy"),
  style: [{
      selector: "node",
      css: {
        content: "data(id)",
        "text-valign": "center",
        "text-halign": "center",
        height: "60px",
        width: "60px"
      }
    },
    {
      selector: ':parent',
      css: {
        //shape: 'rectangle',
        shape: 'cutrectangle',
        //shape: 'roundrectangle',
      }
    },
    {
      selector: "edge",
      css: {
        label: "\u2B24",
        "curve-style": "bezier",
        "target-arrow-shape": "data(arrow)"
      }
    },
    {
      selector: ".selectedNode",
      style: {
        "border-width": 8,
        "border-color": "#5da963"
      }
    }
  ],

  elements: {
    nodes: [{
        data: {
          id: "n0",
          parent: "n4"
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          id: "n1",
          parent: "n5"
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          id: "n2",
          parent: "n5"
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          id: "n3",
          parent: "n5"
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          id: "n4",
          parent: "n5"
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          id: "n5"
        }
      }
    ],
    edges: [{
        data: {
          source: "n0",
          target: "n1",
          arrow: "triangle"
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          source: "n1",
          target: "n2",
          arrow: "triangle"
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          source: "n1",
          target: "n3",
          arrow: "triangle"
        }
      }
    ]
  },

  layout: {
    name: "concentric",
    minNodeSpacing: 140
  }
}));

cy.unbind("click");
cy.bind("click", "node", evt => {
  cy.elements().removeClass("selectedNode");
  evt.target.addClass("selectedNode");
});
```

```css
body {
  font: 14px helvetica neue, helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
}

#cy {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  float: left;
  position: absolute;
}

.cxtmenu-disabled {
  opacity: 0.333;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset=utf-8 />
  <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimal-ui">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/cytoscape@3.10.1/dist/cytoscape.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="cy"></div>
</body>

</html>
```